# what the java command's -jar option really does

Tags: java, jar

Does the `-jar` option of the `java` command also compile the sources before running the main method?
I believe so but i would like to have a better understanding of the internal process, from the man page you can clearly see a small workflow sequence:

```
-jar
             Execute a program encapsulated in a JAR file. The first argument is the name of a JAR file instead of a startup class name. In order for this option to work, the manifest of the JAR file must contain a  line  of
             the form Main-Class: classname. Here, classname identifies the class having the public static void main(String[] args) method that serves as your application's starting point. See the Jar tool reference page and
             the Jar trail of the Java Tutorial @
```

But it does not mention that it compiles the sources.

Comment: As I know the .jar is already compiled and ready to run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does the `-jar` option of the java command also compile the sources before running the main method?

No, absolutely not. It just specifies the `jar` file in which to find the manifest specifying the main class, and (usually) the class file for that class. It definitely *doesn't* compile anything.

Comment: so where does compilation actually takes place?

Comment: @JBoy javac does that for you

Comment: hi thx, this i knew it already, but i though that javac could only be invoked separatelly, apparently `java` embeds a `javac` invocation before passing the bytecode to the VM....(?)

Comment: @JBoy: No, not at all. Where do you get that impression from? The jar file already has to have the class files in it (or available, anyway). You *can't* call `java -jar ...` if you've only got source files. You've got to have compiled them first, and then typically built a jar file *with* those class files.

Comment: ` Where do you get that impression from? ` i had exported a project into a jar via eclipse, i did not see any checkbox or whatsoever that asked me for compilation, so i thought it contained source files, but now when i run a `jar tf` i see that it contains class files

Comment: @JBoy: A jar file containing just source would be somewhat pointless - Eclipse assumes that you wanted the source file in order to package up the compiled code.

Answer (score 2):

The description you posted itself says everything

```
Execute a program encapsulated in a JAR file. The first argument is the name of a JAR file instead of a startup class name. In order for this option to work, the manifest of the JAR file must contain a  line  of the form Main-Class: classname. Here, classname identifies the class having the public static void main(String[] args) method that serves as your application's starting point. See the Jar tool reference page and the Jar trail of the Java
```

Jar files contain a manifest file which has a line of form `Main-Class: classname`. Here the class that contains the main method is given. Its important because standalone application in java begin execution at main method.

Command to run the application packaged in jar looks like :-

```
java -jar jar-file
```

jar-file is name of the jar.

Edit:- And to explicitly answer your question, NO , it does not compile the source code. The jar itself contains compiled class files. You can create jar by addin class files as

```
jar cvf Count.jar Count.class Sum.class
```

jar-command

cvf-options check details here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/build.html

Count.class Sum.class - name of class files(compiled source code) space separated to add in the jar.